# QDataWidgetMapper to map multiple columns to multiple properties of single custom widget

Tags: c++, qt, model-view-controller, qwidget

I've been searching for solutions for days on this. Here's the situation:

I have a custom slider class that have two handles to control a range of doubles, and I created four properties for that:

```
Q_PROPERTY(double minimum MEMBER mMinimum NOTIFY minimumChanged USER true)
Q_PROPERTY(double maximum MEMBER mMaximum NOTIFY maximumChanged USER true)
Q_PROPERTY(double lowerValue MEMBER mLowerValue NOTIFY lowerValueChanged USER true)
Q_PROPERTY(double upperValue MEMBER mUpperValue NOTIFY upperValueChanged USER true)
```

I bind these properties to a QDataWidgetMapper:

```
settingsMapper->addMapping(ui->cutLevelSlider, settings.indexOf("lowerCutLevel"), "lowerValue");
settingsMapper->addMapping(ui->cutLevelSlider, settings.indexOf("upperCutLevel"), "upperValue");
settingsMapper->addMapping(ui->cutLevelSlider, settings.indexOf("minValue"), "minimumValue");
settingsMapper->addMapping(ui->cutLevelSlider, settings.indexOf("maxValue"), "maximumValue")
settingsMapper->toFirst();
```

, hoping that I could have two way updating between the slider and the `settings` item model, which manages a single truth of the setting values. In another word, I am trying to use the slider `cutLevelSlider` as a view to the 4 values min, max, lower, upper stored in model `settings`.

But it does not work. When I slide the slider, only the last property (the upperValue) from the slider get updated to the model, all others does not change. When I change the model through another widget (say, edit from a tableview), the slider status does not change accordingly.

Could anyone help me on this?

Comment: (Assuming that `ui->cutLevelSlider` is a QSlider) Is there a reason for not connecting the slider's [`valueChanged`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractslider.html#valueChanged) signal to arbitrary slots, then modifying the values of your four variables through those slots?

Comment: The idea is that the values are not only viewed/controled by this slider, but also by other widgets. I would like to have 2-way bindings, i.e., when the value is changed by, say, an edit box, I would like to see the slider also changed accordingly. As far as I know, this is exactly the purpose of QDataWidgetMapper, but unfortunately it does not work well with custom widget or non-editing widget even.

Comment: Any update on this one? Also looking for a solution to mapping multiple fields to multiple Qt properties of one same widget. Any workaround would also be appreciated.

Comment: I came to the same topic :) But if you are doing custom widget why not to include QDataWidgetMappers as it's private members? Even if you want to control field names in a model you may make some Bind(fieldname1, fieldname2, ...) method that will take field names and take care of correct binding within custom widger. Not sure how good this idea is but I don't have other and will give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Check https://forum.qt.io/topic/112644/qdatawidgetmapper-to-map-multiple-columns-to-multiple-properties-of-single-custom-widget/3

```
self.mapper = QDataWidgetMapper(self)
        self.mapper.setModel(model)
        self.mapper.addMapping(self.btnLoad, 7, b'enabled')

        self.mapper2 = QDataWidgetMapper(self)
        self.mapper2.setModel(model)
        self.mapper2.addMapping(self.btnLoad, 8, b'text')

        self.mapper.toFirst()
        self.mapper2.toFirst()
```